# How to create log file in asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net

How to create log file in asp.net web application which contains the actions & activities of the applications so that in future i will recover application with the help of that file?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out log4net if you don't want to roll your own.
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/